# В PHPStorm нет нужного интерфейса для результатов Юнит тестов

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpunit

Я смотрел видеоурок по Unit тестированию. И в том видео у рассказчика в программе *PHPStorm* был удобный интерфейс, который показывает детали тестирования:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А у меня ничего подобного. У меня какой-то простецкий:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видео аж 2015 года. Моя версия шторма явно новее: *2018.3*

Может надо поставить какой-то плагин? Почему у меня так отображается и как сделать, чтобы было, как на первой картинке?

Еще я использую *Yii2*, если это имеет значение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что в настроках шторма

```
`Settings` > `Languages & Frameworks` > `PHP` > `PHPUnit`
```

Я выбрал пункт `use Composer autoloader`  и указал путь к скрипту `/vendor/bin/phpunit`.

Когда я установил путь `/vendor/autoload.php`, то всё заработало как ожидалось. Правда чуть с менее богатым интерфейсом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Единственная проблема: мне пришлось принудительно обновиться до версии 2021. Когда я обновился до версии 2021 и кликнул "Run test" шторм показал ошибку:

> Test framework quit unexpectedly

Я поискл и нашёл ответ. Почему *PhpStorm 2018* не показывал мне эту ошибку - я не знаю.